# mount.nfs: mount system call failed

Tags: ubuntu, mount, nfs, hadoop

I am trying to mount hdfs on my local machine running Ubuntu using the following command :---

```
sudo mount -t  nfs  -o vers=3,proto=tcp,nolock 192.168.170.52:/ /mnt/hdfs_mount/
```

But I am getting this error:-

```
mount.nfs: mount system call failed
```

Output for

```
rpcinfo -p 192.168.170.52
```

is

```
        program vers proto   port  service
        100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
        100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
        100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
        100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
        100024    1   udp  48435  status
        100024    1   tcp  54261  status
        100005    1   udp   4242  mountd
        100005    2   udp   4242  mountd
        100005    3   udp   4242  mountd
        100005    1   tcp   4242  mountd
        100005    2   tcp   4242  mountd
        100005    3   tcp   4242  mountd
        100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
```

Output for

```
showmount -e 192.168.170.52
```

is

```
Export list for 192.168.170.52:
/ *
```

I also tried by adding

```
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.groups</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>hadoop.proxyuser.root.hosts</name>
<value>*</value>
</property>
```

in my core-site.xml file located in /etc/hadoop/conf.pseudo. But it did not work.
Please help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

```
sudo mount -t nfs -o vers=3 "remoteIP:/NFS_shares/" "/some/local/Path"
```

Comment: welcomme to U&L I am not sure a mere quoting of argument will help. maybe OP NFS local or remote daemon are not setup properly.

Answer (score -1):

You should upgrade portmap nfs-common. Execute the following command:

```
apt-get upgrade portmap nfs-common
```

Comment: `apt-get upgrade` doesn’t take package names, it upgrades all installed packages for which upgrades are available.

Comment: installing portmap did seem to yield a more useful error message